# How to get the Text of a "dd"-tag?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

[image]

So I'd like to get all the listed words in the "dd"-tag but I don't know how to get them. I mean I tried `String getWord = doc.getElementsByTag("dd").select("a").attr("href");` but it seems like it isn't working. Getting the text of a div is no problem but I just have no clue how the get the text from a "dd" tag and trying getElemenbyTag("dd") doesn't work as well.

The Website: http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/trim.html
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one way you can do this with Jsoup. I would do this:

```
String url ="http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/trim.html";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 ;Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; AppleWebKit/537.36 ;KHTML, like Gecko; Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36")
        .get();

Elements wordAEls = doc.select("dd a");
for (Element wordA : wordAEls ){
    System.out.println(wordA.ownText());    
}
```

Note that I needed to set a proper user agent for this site to respond with html.

The selector just selects all a elements that are located below a dd element.

Comment: Seems like it's working, thanks (the second time I guess ;))!

Comment: Second time? I don't get it. Anyway, you are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

For the link you gave, the words are within **a** tags which are in turn inside **dd** tags.  So here's one way to go about extracting the words via jQuery:

```
$("dd").children().each( function (index, element) {
    console.log( $(this).text() ); 
} );
```

Here I am just printing to the words to the console.  You can also try html() in place of text().